# Iniciar Projeto Vue a partir de template existente

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

É possivel iniciar um projeto `Vue` a partir de um template já existente? Quero criar um template com todas as dependencias necessarias e configurações inicias (assim como paginas e etc), para que sempre, ao fazer um novo projeto, possa iniciar a partir desse template.

Ex: `vue init MyTemplate NomeDoProjeto`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se entendi direito, ou se minha resposta é meio besta, mas creio que você está procurando o [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli). Se não for o que você está procurando, me informe que deleto a resposta.

Conforme a documentação, para instalá-lo precisa executar os comandos abaixo:

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
# or
yarn global add @vue/cli

vue create my-project
```

Existem vários boilerplates do vue-cli, como, por exemplo, o [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en) possui vários como este `vue init vuetifyjs/webpack`.

Você pode inclusive criar o seu próprio se desejar com o comando `vue init username/repo my-project`, onde o username é o seu "username" no Github, e o "repo" é o nome do repositório que você criou.

Comment: Era basicamente isso que eu queria, criar meu proprio template e utilizar, fiz isso e tentei iniciar com ele, mas não funcionou, da o seguinte erro `vue-cli · ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\Rafael\.vue-templates\RafaelAugustoS-Template\template`

Comment: Então, você jogou o que consta no seu computador para um repositório no Github? Se sim, me passe por favor o link do repositório que depois do trabalho eu faço uns testes e tento encontrar o problema.